# Open a second instance of Rythmbox - Ubuntu Karmic Koala 9.10

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, media, workspace

How can I open two instances of Rythmbox on two different workspaces (but I'd like to be able to do it in general)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
rhythmbox -n
```